Safe handle has been closed when accessing name of WindowsIdentity
I am developing an internal webservice using ASP.Net Core 6. The windows identity is provided to the app by IIS when accessing AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().User.
Most times this service works as expected, but I did find multiple log entries, where it threw an ObjectDisposedException (Safe handle has been closed) when accessing the name property of this windows identity. I do not understand where it is coming from, since I am not disposing this service.
The exception:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed.
Object name: 'SafeHandle'.
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Interop.Advapi32.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass, Boolean nullOnInvalidParam)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<GetName>b__55_0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedInternal(SafeAccessTokenHandle token, Action action)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
   at Server.Common.Services.ClaimsPrincipalService.GetCurrentUserAccountName() 

This is the class that accesses the AuthenticationStateProvider:
public class ClaimsPrincipalService
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider;
    private readonly Serilog.ILogger Logger;

    public ClaimsPrincipalService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider, Serilog.ILogger logger)
    {
        AuthenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<string?> GetCurrentUserAccountName()
    {
        try
        {
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;

            if (user.Identity != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && user.Identity.Name != null)
            {
                var identityName = user.Identity.Name;
                int stop = identityName.IndexOf("\\");
                var userId = stop > -1 ? identityName.Substring(stop + 1, identityName.Length - stop - 1) : string.Empty;
                userId = userId.ToUpper();
                return userId;
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Warning("User Identity/Authentication could not be verified");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, "Exception during GetClaimsPrincipalDataAsync method");
        }
        return null;
    }
}

In Program.cs this is added as a scoped service:
builder.Services.AddScoped<ClaimsPrincipalService, ClaimsPrincipalService>();

I have also experimented using a ServerAuthenticationStateProvider, but that service is not available even though I use blazor server side.

You should not inject AuthenticationStateProvider directly in your service. Instead inject it in the component and pass it as a method parameter when needed.
This is what the Microsoft ASP.Net Core docs say:

Don't attempt to resolve AuthenticationStateProvider within a custom
scope because it results in the creation of a new instance of the
AuthenticationStateProvider that isn't correctly initialized.
To access the AuthenticationStateProvider within a service scoped to a
component, inject the AuthenticationStateProvider with the @inject
directive or the [Inject] attribute and pass it to the service as a
parameter. This approach ensures that the correct, initialized
instance of the AuthenticationStateProvider is used for each user app
instance.

Inject AuthenticationStateProvider for services scoped to a component
